# How do I fix these absurd side effects of migrating to Joomla! 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

I am tasked with migrating a web site from *Joomla! 1.5* to *Joomla! 2.5*. That's been a mess, but I finally have the site running.

Here is a chunk of code from one of my articles:

```
<p><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">Description </span><span class="Apple-style-span" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;"><br /></span></p>
<p>A bunch of text goes here</p>
<p style="font-size: 10px;" align="center"><a href="some_image.jpg" target="_PCI-104-3000"> <img src="another_image.jpg" border="1" alt="Image of The Thing" height="120px" />
```

When I mouse over the paragraph in the middle there ("A bunch of text goes here"), or the title line above it, the entire paragraph turns bold. When the mouse leaves that area, the text returns to normal.

Why? This is the exact same code being run on the *Joomla! 1.5* version of the site, and over there it isn't doing this. Does the new version of *Joomla!* have a problem reading HTML?

Comment: As you well know, J2.5 is anything but 'the exact same code' - I'd suggest comparing both sites with firebug, and see what the CSS differences are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I could see the actual site with the problem, I could tell you exactly where, but clearly you have some CSS in the *new* site that is triggering a :hover.  Check the CSS files of the J2.5 version of your template.

Comment: Ah, the template! I was looking at the article specifically, but you're right; whatever jUpgrade did to "migrate" my template from 1.5 to 2.5, it messed with the CSS and put some :hover triggers in that weren't there before. That's really obnoxious. It's fixed now though, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help - you should look at finding a J2.5 version of the template to avoid any other hurdles that you're likely to encounter.

Comment: That's probably the way to go. It's actually a custom template we had built for us way back when 1.5 was new, but I might try getting us on a more stable track if it looks like we're going to keep using Joomla for this kind of thing.